# Three terminal LED pilot. What's the matter?

Tags: led, optoelectronics

Long story short, I've purchased a 24VDC LED pilot and I've got a 12VDC pilot with three terminals instead. I was wondering what are each one of those three terminals for, the terminals have standard names (X0, X1, X2) but in the case there are additional names written (C, S, T respectively).

All the google searches I've done lead to me to electronic LED flashers but I don't think this is what I'm looking for. The LED has no serial number I could use to check it out.

This is the symbol printed in the case:

[image]

EDIT1:

I've asked the manufacturer for documentation and they've sent me the datasheet, this LED has lamp test function and the additional terminal serves to connect to a lamp test circuit (whatever it is).

[image]

Comment: What is a pilot?

Comment: @winny a pilot light is just an indicator light, like the blinking lights used in cars.

Comment: @Andyaka Unfortunately there's no documentation available, the only thing I have is this link  (http://www.technapower.com/products/led-pilot-lights/ledtec) from the manufacturer but no specific documentation since I it doesn't have a serial number. Maybe the wise thing to do is to ask the manufacturer....

Comment: To clarify, a *pilot light* is an old term, a light that indicates that *power is on*, not just any indicator light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Industrial control panels often have a lamp test feature to check that all lamps are functional. This is less important nowadays with the switchover to LEDs which have a much longer lifespan than incandescent bulbs.

One of the problems to be dealt with is prevention of backfeeds from the test circuit. For example, if the lamp is connected in parallel with a relay then some means of preventing the relay from being energised during lamp test must be employed. On DC lamps a couple of diodes can usually provide a solution. It appears that in your product the diodes have been included in the indicator housing. Nice!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzChqO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Likely internal indicator circuit and sample external circuit including test switch.*

I expect that you should find internal diodes to prevent backfeed from the test circuit into the control circuits and vice versa. I would also be quite confident that SIG and TEST terminals could be swapped without a problem.